# Coworkers, employees

Tags: word-request

1. If I was the head of a department in a company, what would I then call the people in that department (who work under me)?
2. If I was the boss of a company, would the people in the company be my employees or are they only employees of the company or the person who owns the company?

Answer (score 2):

1. You may hear them called employees, but one common phrase that comes to mind is to say that they are "my team" (collectively) or "a member of my team" or "one of my team".
2. In this context I think you would definitely hear them called employees, even though they are technically employees of the company. You may also hear them called by their title and possibly described as "our" instead of "my", e.g., "he's one of my/our engineers", "she's one of my/our heads of department".

Answer (score 2):

1. One word used in business today is **colleague**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/colleague) says

> **colleague**
> NOUN
>
> A person with whom one works in a profession or business.

When this term is used by a manager in relation to those working in that department, it implies that they are all working *together*. Those who work there know who is boss, but a working relationship can be better if it isn't stressed more often than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. People who work directly under you are said to **"report to"** you. You can also call them your **"direct reports"**.
2. They are employees of the company. Unless you are also an owner of the company, I wouldn't call them your employees. Some might, but I think this one is a matter of prefernce.